# Have some works by Émile Borel ever been translated from French to English or another foreign language?

Tags: pr.probability, ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy

I plan to submit a couple of questions around Émile Borel's works in probability theory to MO.

In this scope, I'd like to know if the following works have ever been translated from French to English or another foreign language:

- *Le hasard* (*Randomness*), second edition, 1947;
- *Sur les probabilités universellement négligeables* (*On universally negligible probabilities*), 1930, Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Académie des Sciences, 190, pp. 537-40;
- *Valeur pratique et philosophie des probabilités* (*Practical value and philosophy of probabilities*), 1939.

Besides, is it possible to find an electronic copy of Borel's complete works in four volumes somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mathscinet, the following books by Borel on probability have been translated to English and Russian:

MR0177424 Borel, Émile Elements of the theory of probability. Translated by John E. Freund Prentice-Hall, Inc., Englewood Cliffs, N.J. 1965

MR0169314 Borel, Émile Probabilities and life. Translated from the French by Maurice Baudin Dover Publications, Inc., New York 1962

MR0039932 Borel, Émile Probabilité et certitude. (French) Presses Universitaires de France, Paris, 1950 (translated into Russian).

Besides these "Space and time", and "Lectures on divergent series" were translated into English.

EDIT. Zentralblatt is more complete for translations. It shows the same 3 books in English, 3 more in Russian (on elementary mathematics) and and 5 books in German: 4 on elementary mathematics and one on aviation. I trust Zentralblatt, and suppose this list is complete.

Comment: @ Alexandre. Thank you very much for your input. So, the other works by Borel I'm talking about might not have been translated. This is another good motivation for my questions to come soon... Thanks again

Comment: @FabricePautot - it seems that there is also an [English translation](https://books.google.it/books/about/Probability_and_Certainty.html?id=Ljc4AAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) of *Probabilité et certitude*.

Comment: @ Alexandre. Sorry I can't validate your answer because that's not the same material. But I appreciate.

Comment: Same for Mauro.

Comment: @Fabrice Pautot: I do not understand your last two remarks: you "do not validate" because nobody cared to translate the books you asked about? But this is not our fault:-)

Comment: @Alexandre: I can't validate because I'm expecting answers like "the works you mention have been translated in this or this language" or "I can tell you they haven't been translated in this or this language". But if you want me to validate them, I can do it!

Comment: @Alexandre: OK, I validate, but I'd like to get more answers.