# Has a discrete/quantum theory of probability based on the Cournot-Borel principle or something been developed?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, ho.history-overview

In 1930, Émile Borel, the father of measure theory together with his student Lebesgue and a world-class expert in probability theory, published a short note *Sur les probabilités universellement négligeables* (*On universally negligible probabilities*) in Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Académie des Sciences, 190, pp. 537-40. Here it is:

http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3143v.f539

According to this question

[Have some works by Émile Borel ever been translated from French to English or another foreign language?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236758/have-some-works-by-%C3%89mile-borel-ever-been-translated-from-french-to-english-or-an)

and to the best of my knowledge, this note has never been translated in any foreign language. I would be happy to translate it entirely upon request despite my poor English.

Borel is concerned by Cournot principle. As the bridge, the connection between the mathematical theory of probability and the real world of experience,Borel considers Cournot principle to be the most important and fundamental principle of probability theory: he used to call it the *fundamental law of randomness* or the *unique law of randomness*. Hence, Borel seeks for a quantitative version of Cournot principle. He starts like this:

*We know that, in the applications of the calculus of probability, when the probability becomes extremely close to unity, it can and must be practically confounded with certainty. Carnot principle, the irreversibility of many phenomena, are well-known examples in which the theoretical probability equals practical certainty. However, we may not have, at least to the best of my knowledge, sufficiently specified from which limits a probability becomes universally negligible, that is negligible in the widest limits of time and space that we can humanly conceive, negligible in our whole universe.*

and concludes, by a **purely physical reasoning** (emphases by Borel):

*The conclusion that must be drawn is that the probabilities that can be expressed by a number smaller than ${10^{ - 1000}}$ are not only negligible in the common practice of life, but universally negligible, that is they must be treated as **rigorously equal to zero*** *in every questions regarding our Universe. The fact that they are not effectively null may be of interest for the metaphysicist; for the scientist they **are*** *null and the phenomena to which they relate are absolutely **impossible***.

This *Cournot-Borel principle*

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
p \in \left[ {{{0,10}^{ - 1000}}} \right]\;\;\;\;\,\; \Rightarrow p = 0\quad \quad {\rm{Borel - supracosmic}}\;{\rm{probabilities}}\\
p \in \left[ {1 - {{10}^{ - 1000}},1} \right] \Rightarrow p = 1\quad \quad \,{\rm{Borel - supercosmic}}\;{\rm{probabilities}}
\end{array} \right.$

implies that there are only discrete probability measures/distributions in *every probabilistic questions regarding our universe*.

Indeed, consider for instance a cumulative distribution function $F\left( x \right):\mathbb{R} \to \left[ {0,1} \right]$. Suppose $F\left( x \right)$ is left-continuous at some point ${x_0}$, that is $F\left( x \right)$ is continuous at ${x_0}$ since it is right-continuous by definition:

$\forall \varepsilon  > 0\;\exists \eta  > 0,\forall x,{x_0} - \eta  < x < {x_0} \Rightarrow \left| {F\left( x \right) - F\left( {{x_0}} \right)} \right| = F\left( {{x_0}} \right) - F\left( x \right) = {\text{Prob}}\left( {y \in \left[ {x,{x_0}} \right]} \right) = \mu \left( {\left[ {x,{x_0}} \right]} \right) < \varepsilon $

In particular, by the Cournot-Borel principle

$\forall {10^{ - 1000}} > \varepsilon  > 0\;\exists \eta  > 0,\forall x,{x_0} - \eta  < x < {x_0} \Rightarrow \mu \left( {\left[ {x,{x_0}} \right]} \right) = 0$

Hence, either $F\left( x \right)$ is constant or it is discontinuous: $F\left( x \right)$ is nothing but a discrete cumulative distribution function or cumulative mass function.

Hence, following Borel, at least two different mathematical theories of probability would coexist: the mathematical, *metaphysical*, continuous one that relies heavily on measure theory, and the *scientific*, physical, discrete one where measure theory is almost irrelevant.

This *Borel-Cournot discrete theory of probability* is not necessarily inconsistent nor trivial because continuous r.v.s have discrete probability measures. By construction and definition, it constitutes another potential answer or proposal to Hilbert sixth problem or program. We can also talk about a *quantum theory of (classical and quantum?) probability* (not the theory of quantum probability) with Borel *probabilistic quanta* $b = {10^{ - 1000}}$, analogous to the energy quanta in QM. Of course, this value should be updated according to our modern knowledge about the Universe.

Has something like this theory ever been developed? 
I would be happy with **non-probabilistic answers** too, *i.e.* mathematical theories formalizing such a concept of *finite resolution* and *indistinguishability*. I found such a theory many years ago but I don't remember!

Comment: C'est _Carnot_, non?

Comment: @YemonChoi. No, Cournot principle in probability theory and Carnot principle in thermodynamics.

Comment: Google is showing me several articles by G. Shafer on the history of Cournot's principle, which seem to argue that it can indeed form part of an alternative approach to probability. But I am not competent to judge the results

Comment: I'm not an expert in history or measure theory, but I don't see why we should take it seriously. In my view, modern measure theory perfectly resolves the issue raised by Borel in these writings, by allowing sets with probability measure zero that are nonetheless "possible" (in the support). If one is concerned with practical physics rather than theoretical mathematics, there are many phenomena which are actually discrete but are modeled with continuous mathematics (e.g. a volume of liquid is actually a finite collection of molecules); why not probability as well?

Comment: Why do you call a published paper of Borel a "confidential note"? Because it is published in French?

Comment: @YemonChoi. I'm aware of the series of papers by Shafer and Vovk (Ph.D. student of Kolmogorov) about the sources of the Grundbegriffe. Kolmogorov was also concerned by Cournot principle but it seems that Borel went much farther in this line or reasoning.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko. Absolutely right. I've been able to find only a very few papers citing this paper by Borel, most of them from French writers.

Comment: @Fabrice Pautot: I suppose that at that time all mathematicians (even American ones:-) could read mathematical papers in French. And the French ones could even read Russian!

Comment: with respect to an English text by Borel on this topic, see chapter 3 "Negligible probabilities and the probabilities of everyday life" in the Dover edition "Probabilities and Life" (1962).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker. Thanks for the reference, i'll check it.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker. Does Borel make such a strong statement in his English paper?

Answer (score 13):

This question belongs more to philosophy rather than mathematics, so it might be out of scope of this site. But the general answer is that mathematical models are only an approximation to reality, and we choose those approximations which are convenient. For example, we can discover sometimes that the space/time is not really continuous but consists of some discrete objects. But this will not make calculus based on the concept of real number useless or obsolete. One can argue without end whether real numbers really correspond to something "real". Nevertheless they are useful in physics and engineering. (See, for example,
N. J. Wildberger, Real fish, real numbers, real jobs, The Mathematical Intelligencer, Volume 21, Issue 2, pp 4–7.)

Same with probability. Continuous distributions historically arise as approximations to discrete distributions
(normal distribution is an approximation of the binomial distribution via the de Moivre-Laplace theorem). But normal distribution is much nicer from the mathematical point of view and therefore it must be used, even if when the "real" distribution under consideration is binomial.

In other words, the accepted axioms of Probability are chosen (from the several proposed systems) because of their mathematical convenience, rather than because they better approximate the "real world" from the philosophical point of view.

(Of the systems of mathematical foundations of probability which were competing
with Kolmogorov's axioms, I can mention those proposed by S. Bernstein, R. von Mises and H. Steinhaus. And philosophic considerations played a secondary role in the choice).

Remark: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUdFdlQNfpg) is Wildberger's reading of his paper on Youtube, for those who have no subscription for Intelligencer.

Comment: We apply probability theory to mathematical phenomena. In this 
case small probabilities occur. For example  R.  Brent,   van de Lune, and I compute the probability of $|\arg(\zeta(\sigma+it)|>\pi/2$ for $\sigma=1.165$
as $1.279\dots\times10^{-283}$ and this really happens for some $t$. We can obtain smaller
probabilities for other $\sigma>1$.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko . Sorry if you don't find this thread mathematical enough. But there are tags for historical and philosophical aspects of maths in MO, so that I hope discussing "philosophical" works... by well-known mathematicians is not too much out of scope.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko. The problem is precisely that Borel philosophical considerations seemsto have some drastic mathematical consequences! Do you agree that this "Cournot-Borel principle" implies that there are only discrete probability measures in every questions regarding our universe???

Comment: @alexandre eremenko. My question nevertheless pertains to Hilbert sixth problem. Discrete or not discrete, that is the question. Is quantifying Cournot principle not a kind of mathematical physics? I propose to cross-post the question on PO if MO doesn't mind.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko Some years ago, I bought an original copy of Borel Le hasard (Randomness), second edition, 1947. Believe it or not, the book was brand new, I cut the sheets by myself! Tried to find his complete works in 4 volumes but no way. Not exactly best sellers!

Comment: @alexandre eremenko My question is 100% mathematical: take probability theory and add a new non-trivial axiom, the Cournot-Borel principle.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko I did my best to make the question more mathematical. On the philosophical side, it is worth observing that Borel considers the current, continuous, measure-theoretic theory as the metaphysical, philosophical one. I'm asking for the discrete, quantum, scientific and physical one.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko As you pointed it out, just like space quantification can yield interesting theories like quantum loop gravity, even the purest mathematician can wonder if we can ever get something interesting (mathematically but not only) by quantifying probability as well, as suggested by Borel. Of course, just like QM does not make classical physics obsolete or irrelevant, quite the opposite, both continuous and quantum theories of probability are not mutually exclusive (a priori).

Comment: @alexandre eremenko My favorite axiomatic system of probability is R. T. Cox's. Bernstein's is nice too, as far as I can remember.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko We can mention A. Renyi's axiomatic system too, that  accomodates for improper probability distributions  (that would certainly disappear in the Cournot-Borel theory).

Comment: @alexandre eremenko A priori, any system of probability can be Cournot-Borel quantified. Moreover, quantification may depend on the interpretation of probability, e.g. fequentist or Bayesian...

Comment: @juan For what set does your "we" stand please? As you know, Borel also made good use of PT in pure maths, including number theory like you (Borel normal numbers...). No doubt he would appreciate your nice results on the zeroes of the zeta function... that really happen in the mathematical world. But, as many others, Borel had much interest in the applications of mathematics too, not only in the physical sciences but also in game theory (Théorie mathématique du bridge). And not only PT but also geometry for instance (Introduction géométrique à quelques théories physiques).

Comment: @juan Conversely, a pure mathematician does not need to know the reasons why a mathematical axiom like this Cournot-Borel principle was introduced in order to explore and develop the corresponding theory, isn't it? That's the reason why my question may be of interest for some pure mathematicians as well. But clearly, it should sound more interesting for those who care about the applications of maths to the real world.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko Given that Borel reasoning is purely physical, there is nothing metaphysical or philosophical in this story. Philosophical tag removed. I would be happy with non-probabilistic answers too, i.e. mathematical theories formalizing concepts such as finite resolution and indistinguishability.

Comment: @alexandre eremenko As one example of the kind of mathematics we may miss if we don't care about the real world/physics, please see my unanswered question about probability theory and dynamical system theory:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232043/whats-the-probability-distribution-of-a-deterministic-signal-or-how-to-marginal . If we could ever compute those probability distributions, we could solve many practical signal processing problems quite easily. But unfortunately, it seems that nobody can.